# How to call bcrypt inside axios call

Tags: javascript, express, axios, bcrypt

I was doing an axios call to a certain json file. Basically I am trying to get an input from a front end framework and passing the data to my server via express.

So what am I trying to do here is that I want to encrypt first the password that I got from `request.body.password` before saving it to the database.

The default documentation from bcrypt, is an asynchronous call using callbacks so what I did is I console log the result before and after the encryption but it seems that bycrypt only works inside itself and doesn't encrypt the password before saving it to the database.

```
router.post('/call/user', (req, res) => {
  var user = new User(req.body);
    axios
        .get(
          `http://localhost:3000/mydata/data.json`
        )
        .then(response => {
          user.lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
          user.lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

          console.log('here is the user password... >>>>>>>>>', req.body.password) // returns original text password

            bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, function(err, hash){
              if(err){
                console.log(err);
              }
              user.password = hash;
            });

            console.log('this is the hash password >>>>>>>>>', user.password)
// i expect this to return the encrypted password but it seems it doesn't encrypt it outside the callback


         // saving data to user
          user.save(err => {
            if (err) {
              console.log('problem adding user', err);
            } else {
              res.status(200).send();
            }
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('err on user', err);
          res.status(500).send();
        });
});
```

In the end, if I console.log this it will show me the original text password without encryption on it save to the db.

Any idea what am I missing here? How can fixed my function to do the things I want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the technique 1?

```
bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, salt, function(err, hash) {
        // Store hash in your password DB.
    });
});
```

And then just return the user.password?

Comment: I believe my function works but it's just that I need to find a way to use the output encrypted password before saving it to the db..